# Can I make my gaussian moving average on high resolution data any faster?

Tags: python, cython

I need a gaussian moving average to smooth and resample data. For example data with starting with a resolution of 1 m and then resampling so the data has a resolution of 2 km.

The width of the boxes for the Gaussian need to include 3 times the standard deviation. There are also some assumptions I make because I can, the initial data is a square, and the final resolution needed equally divides the original data into boxes.

I am currently using python 3.7 with cython. How could I make this faster?

```
    import numpy as np
    cimport numpy as np

    cimport cython
    
    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.cdivision(True)

    cdef symmetric_g(int length_window, long center, int std):
        """
        :param length_window: length L 
        :param center: center of window 
        :param std: roll off for Gaussian standard deviation 
        :return: gaussian weights size L x L 
        """
        cdef np.ndarray[dtype = double, ndim = 1] L, weights
        cdef np.ndarray[dtype = double, ndim = 2 ] weights2D

        L = np.linspace(0, length_window, length_window)
        weights = np.exp(-(L - center) ** 2 / (2 * std) ** 2)
        weights2D = np.outer(weights, weights)
        return weights2D


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)

def gauss_moving(data, int resolution, int final_res, int std):

    cdef:
        int xdim, ydim, box_width, half_width, half_pad, padded_width
        int wx, wy, count, end_point, i , j
        long sum_weights, accume
        list ave = []

    #Pad data 3*std for allow for boxes on edges to be appropriate size
    data_padded = np.pad(data, 3 * std, 'constant', constant_values=np.nan)
    xdim, ydim = data_padded.shape
    box_width = final_res // resolution

    half_width = box_width // 2
    padded_width = box_width + (3 * std) * 2

    half_pad = padded_width // 2

    weights_central = symmetric_g(padded_width, half_width, std)
    sum_weights = np.sum(weights_central)
    wx, wy = np.asarray(weights_central).shape

    count = 0
    end_point = xdim - 3 * std
    for i in range(half_pad, end_point, box_width):
        for j in range(half_pad, end_point, box_width):
            box = data_padded[i - half_pad:i + half_pad, j - half_pad: j + half_pad]
            count += 1
            if np.sum(np.isnan(box)) == 0:
                print('if')
                accume = 0
                for k in range(wx):
                    for L in range(wy):
                        accume += box[k, L] * weights_central[k, L]
                ave.append(accume / sum_weights)
            else:
                print('else')
                #check for edge nan values and adjust weights 
                #nans will be excluded from weight calculation 
                loc_nans = np.where(np.isnan(box))
                weight_nans = weights_central.copy()
                weight_nans[loc_nans] = np.nan
                weight_nan_sum = np.nansum(weight_nans)

                accume = 0
                if np.sum(np.isnan(weight_nans)) == np.sum(np.isnan(box)):
                    for k in range(wx):
                        for L in range(wy):
                            accume += np.nansum(box[k, L] * weight_nans[k, L])
                    average = np.nansum(accume / weight_nan_sum)
                    ave.append(average)
    return ave
```

Comment: My rule of thumb is that if you need to do `for` loops with numpy, you're doing something in a non-optimal way, and I can see multiple here...

Comment: @AKX I am coming at this from a scientific computing background, and this needs to be legible for my colleagues who use FORTRAN which is why the loops are helpful. Additionally I believe the loops are faster in this case because of the use of Cython.

Comment: @AKX One of the main advantages Cython gives you is that it makes for loops with Numpy fast (basically C speed, if they're typed correctly). So that isn't cause for alarm by itself. But writing vectorized expressions is still a good idea if it's easy and exists.

Comment: Fair points. Numba might be an option beside Cython, anyway.

Comment: @drwnthembirds Try running `cython -a yourfilename.pyx` - it'll give you an annotated html file with some hints about what's optimized